# Headstart needed for re-using the register functionality in Laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel-5

I am building a Laravel 5.0 project. With this the admin section is only accessible for registered users. I have added for example a user type to the User model and want to create and edit users using an admin module instead of the standard registration form in /auth/register.

But I cannot seem to find how to disable /auth/register for the outside world, but also cannot create my own CRUD for managing users.

So my main two questions are:

- How can I reuse the password encryption in my own create and update functionality
- How can I disable /auth/register for the not logged in users?

Thanx in advance

Comment: Why don't you just use the built in users for both types of account and just add a flag to the users table to identify whether they are an admin, or better yet use [entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) to add roles and permissions?

Comment: That is what I want to do. Only I cannot see where I can set that /auth/register is only accessible for admins and when I parse the aut/register form into a regular crud page, it isn't saving the user at all

Comment: just remove the register route, and make a new form for the admins to create new users

Comment: OK, found a way to disable the register functionality. The only question left is how do I make a create form where the password is encrypted like the auth controller does?

Comment: OK, found it. bcrypt($request->password) did the trick